# ErrorException Undefined variable: code (View: C:\wamp\www\secureserver\app\views\emails\adminverify.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

I have been toiling around to no avail of Solutions Please help. It seems my View cannot read the $code and $user variable respectively from my Controller

Here is the part of my controller that the $code and $user Variables are been instantiated respectively:

UserController.php

```
public function varifyMail($code){
if(User::where('varification_code','=',$code)->update(['varification_status'=>1])){
    return Redirect::route('login')
                        ->with('success', 'Account varified.');
}else{
    return Redirect::route('login')
                        ->with('error', 'Varification Failed.Try again');
}





);

$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

if($validation->fails()){

    return Redirect::route('login')
                        ->with('error', 'Invalid Email Address. Try again.');

}else{
    $code = str_random(25);

    $userUpdate = ['recovery_code' => $code];
    User::where('email','=',Input::get('email'))->update($userUpdate);
    $data = ['code'=>$code];

    //send mail
    Mail::send('emails.recover',$data,function($message){
            $message->to(Input::get('email'))->subject('Recover Your Account.');
        });
    return Redirect::route('login')
                        ->with('success', 'Request Send successfully.Please Recover Your Account.');
    //return User::where('email','=',Input::get('email'))->get();
}










    Auth::login($user);
    return View::make('users.edit')
        ->with('title','Update Cridentials')
        ->with('user',User::where('id','=',$user->id)->first());
}else{
    return Redirect::route('login')
                        ->with('error', 'Recovery Failed.Try again');

}
```

And this is my view:
Adminverify.blade.php

```
<div class="header-content"><webversion><a href="{{URL::route('mail.varification',$code)}}">Web Version</a></webversion><span class="hide">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; <preferences lang="en"><a href="{{URL::route('login')}}">Update preferences</a></preferences>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
```

But whenever I try using it it get this error:

```
ErrorException
```

Undefined variable: code (View: C:\wamp\www\secureserver\app\views\emails\adminverify.blade.php)

Any Help will be highly Appreciated Thanks!

Thanks for your prompt response but it happens to be that it did not work but here is my entire Controller with the Varify changed to Verify as cadmium suggested so we can be sure what exactly could be the challenge.

```
class UserController extends BaseController {


private function verify($email){
    $verify = User::where('email','=',$email)->first();
    if(! is_null($verify)){
        if($verify->role_id==2){
            return $verify->distributor_approve & $verify->varification_status;
        }else{
            return $verify->varification_status;
        }

    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

/**
 * login page
 * @return void
 */
public function login()
{
    return View::make('users.login')
                    ->with('title', 'Log in');
}


/**
 * process to login a user
 * @return void
 */
public function doLogin()
{
    $rules = array
    (
        'email'     => 'required|email',
        'password'  => 'required'
    );
    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validation->fails())
        return Redirect::route('login')
                            ->withInput()
                            ->withErrors($validation);
    else
    {
        $credentials = array
        (
            'email'     =>  Input::get('email'),
            'password'  =>  Input::get('password')
        );

        if($this->verify(Input::get('email')) && Auth::attempt($credentials))
        {
            Session::put('role', Auth::user()->role_id);

            //return User::where('id','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
            if(User::where('id','=',Auth::user()->id)->first()->first_login == 0){

                return Redirect::route('info.create',[Auth::user()->id]);
            }

            return Redirect::intended('/');
        }
        else
            return Redirect::route('login')
                                ->withInput()
                                ->with('error', 'Error in Email Address or Password.');
    }
}

/**
 * logout a user
 * @return void
 */
function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    Session::forget('role');

    return Redirect::route('login')
                    ->with('success', 'You have been logged out.');
}

public function show(){

    $pages= Page::orderby('title')->get();
    if(Auth::check()){
        if(Auth::user()->role_id==1){
            return View::make('public.pages.admin')
                    ->with('title', "Home");
        }
    }
    return View::make('public.pages.show')
                    ->with('title', "Home")
                    ->with('pages',$pages);
}

public function register()
{
    return View::make('users.register')
                    ->with('title', 'Register');
}

public function doRegister()
{
    //return Input::all();



    $rules = array
    (
        'username'  =>  'required|min:3|max:15',
        'email'     => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' =>'Required|Confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' =>'Required',
        'role'  =>  'Required',
        'agree' =>  'Required',
        'recaptcha_response_field' => 'required|recaptcha'

    );
    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validation->fails())
        return Redirect::route('register')
                            ->withInput()
                            ->withErrors($validation);
    else
    {
        if(Input::get('role')==3){
            $user = new User;
            $user->user_name      = Input::get('username');
            $user->email      = Input::get('email');
            $user->password      = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->role_id        = Input::get('role');
            $code = str_random(25);
            $user->varification_code        = $code;
            $data = ['username'=>Input::get('username'),'code'=>$code];
            Mail::send('emails.validate',$data,function($message){
                $message->to(Input::get('email'))->subject('Please Verify Your Email.');
            });


            if($user->save())
            return Redirect::route('home')
                                ->with('success', "Verify Your Account.");
        else
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation)->with('error', 'Some error occured. Try again.');
        }else{

            $user = new User;
            $user->user_name      = Input::get('username');
            $user->email      = Input::get('email');
            $user->password      = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->role_id        = Input::get('role');
            $user->distributor_status = 1;
            $code = str_random(25);
            $user->varification_code        = $code;
            $data = ['username'=>Input::get('username'),'code'=>$code];
            Mail::send('emails.validate',$data,function($message){
                $message->to(Input::get('email'))->subject('Please Verify Your Email.');
            });


            if($user->save())
                return Redirect::route('home')
                                    ->with('success', "Request Send successfully.Please Verify Your Email.");
            else
                return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation)->with('error', 'Some error occured. Try again.');
        }



    }
}

public function edit(){
    return View::make('users.edit')
        ->with('title','Update Cridentials')
        ->with('user',User::where('id','=',Auth::user()->id)->first());
}

public function update(){
    $rules = array
    (
        'username'  =>  'required|min:3|max:15',    
        'password' =>'Required|Confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' =>'Required'


    );
    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validation->fails())
        return Redirect::back()
                            ->withInput()
                            ->withErrors($validation);
    else
    {


        $userUpdate = ['user_name' => Input::get('username'),
            'password'=>Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
            ];



        if(User::find(Auth::user()->id)->update($userUpdate)){

            Auth::logout();
            Session::forget('role');

            return Redirect::route('login')
                            ->with('success', 'Your Cridentials Have Been Changed.');

        }

        else
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation)->with('error', 'Some error occured. Try again.');


    }
}

public function verifyMail($code){
    if(User::where('varification_code','=',$code)->update(['varification_status'=>1])){
        return Redirect::route('login')
                            ->with('success', 'Account varified.');
    }else{
        return Redirect::route('login')
                            ->with('error', 'Varification Failed.Try again');
    }

}

public function passwordRecover(){
    $rules = array
    (
        'email'     => 'required|email'

    );

    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

    if($validation->fails()){

        return Redirect::route('login')
                            ->with('error', 'Invalid Email Address. Try again.');

    }else{
        $code = str_random(25);

        $userUpdate = ['recovery_code' => $code];
        User::where('email','=',Input::get('email'))->update($userUpdate);
        $data = ['code'=>$code];

        //send mail
        Mail::send('emails.recover',$data,function($message){
                $message->to(Input::get('email'))->subject('Recover Your Account.');
            });
        return Redirect::route('login')
                            ->with('success', 'Request Send successfully.Please Recover Your Account.');
        //return User::where('email','=',Input::get('email'))->get();
    }


}

public function mailRecover($code){
    $user = User::where('recovery_code','=',$code)->first();
    if(! is_null($user)){

        Auth::login($user);
        return View::make('users.edit')
            ->with('title','Update Cridentials')
            ->with('user',User::where('id','=',$user->id)->first());
    }else{
        return Redirect::route('login')
                            ->with('error', 'Recovery Failed.Try again');

    }
}



    /**
 * Show a  page
 * @param  string $pageUrl
 * @return void
 */
public function pages($pageUrl = 'home')
{
    try
    {
        $page = Page::where('url', '=', $pageUrl)->firstOrFail();

/*
        if($page->id == 1)  $layout = 'layouts.home';
        else                $layout = 'layouts.default';
*/


$layout = 'layouts.default';
        return View::make('public.pages.publicShow')
                    ->with('title', "$page->title")
                    ->with('page', $page)
                    ->with('layout', $layout);
    }
    catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
    {
       return "Page not found.";
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't speak to the particulars of laravel, but there are some variances in the way you are spelling "varify", but in other places "verify" is reverences. I would check to make sure you are spelling things consistently first.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you need to have `View::make("adminverify")`. I don't see it in the code you've posted, but it's there somewhere. You need to pass the `$code` value to this view, like so:

```
View::make("adminverify")->with("code", "some code value");
```

Once you do that, the `$code` variable will be available in the template.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response but it happens to be that it did not work but here is my entire Controller with the Varify changed to Verify as cadmium suggested so we can be sure what exactly could be the challenge.<?php

Comment: I can't see that you've addressed the issue I raised in my answer. According to your question, you have a template called `Adminverify.blade.php`, right? And the error you're getting is an undefined variable called `$code` in that file, right? I don't see a reference to that template anywhere in the code you posted. Are you importing it in one of your other templates? Rendering it from another controller? Post that code, and we can begin to see what the problem might be.